# Audio channelising?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

What I want to know is, if there is anyway on an iOS device to channelise a sound out of loudspeaker. With channelising I mean left, center or right channelising of sound out of speaker.
Lets say I have a slider and if slider is in center it means sound should come out equally from both the speakers but if it is slided towards left hand side then left hand side speaker volume should decrease & at the same time right hand side speaker volume should increase.

Comment: What you'd like to have is called `balance control` in English. And ti works more intuitively, if pulled left, the left speaker is louder...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using an `AVAudioPlayer`, the [`pan`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAudioPlayer/pan) property controls the balance/channel:

> By setting this property you can position a sound in the stereo field. A value of –1.0 is full left, 0.0 is center, and 1.0 is full right.